# how to access token from lightning web components

Tags: lightning-web-components, authentication

we are building custom parts of salesforce with `lightning web components`. Salesforce instance will use third party authentication Okta. In those widgets we will need to have access to token, or somehow add token which we will use to our request to reach out our backend service api.  How we can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function in Apex class that performs to return the authentication token or whatever logic you want. Now define this function in your LWC javascript and store the token by invoking the function anywhere in your LWC javascript.

Example Apex Code:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String getAuthToken(){
        List<Okta_Auth__c> auths = [SELECT Id, Token__c
                FROM Okta_Auth__c
                WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
                LIMIT 1];
        if(auths.size() > 0){
            return auths[0].Token__c;
        }
        return '';      
    }
```

LWC JS Code:

```
import getAuthToken from "@salesforce/apex/DataController.getAuthToken";

const token = getAuthToken({});
```